# to_char, to_date in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g, to-char

I'm trying to convert the following command:

```
to_char(to_date('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+((1442998800)/( 60 * 60 * 24 )+(180/1440)),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But with no success, any help is greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why Oracle and Sql Server Both?? Please tag ur question correctly. And however Sql Server doesnt support to_char function.

Comment: Maybe to_char is Oracle?

Comment: This works in oracle, i want to convert it so it works in sql server

Comment: Seems like some kind of date add to me. it would be simpler to answer if you can provide input and desired output.

Comment: the input is 1442998800 and the output is 23/09/2015 12:00:00

Comment: so this is some kind of translator between a big int and a datetime?

Comment: if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Input int = 1442998800
SELECT dateadd(second, @Input, '1970-01-01 03:00:00')
```

[see fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/5288)

Explenation: it's clear that the input is the number of seconds since a specific date - turns out that date is January first, 1970, at 3 am.

Comment: It works thanks very much Zohar you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND,1442998800,'1970-01-01'),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

In words' it adds 1442998800 seconds to 1970-01-01 and formats it the way you decsribed. Give it a try ;-)

Comment: no problem variations of how to do it are always helpful ;) thanks alot